# SolidWorks CAM api

Tags: c#, solidworks

I want to create an add-in that can automate some of our workflow in SolidWorks CAM 2021.
According to this help page, it is possible to access the API of other addins:
https://help.solidworks.com/2018/English/api/sldworksapiprogguide/Overview/Accessing_Add-ins.htm

However I'm not sure what to do after using GetAddInObject on the SolidWorks CAM addin.
This guy seem to have a solution for VB, but doesn't present the actual implementation.

This is the code I have so far:

```
dynamic SWCAMObject = default(dynamic);
dynamic SWCAM = default(dynamic);

SWCAMObject = iSwApp.GetAddInObject("{CCAC6208-0E19-6455-2017-2021CEB541FA}");
if (SWCAMObject == null) ErrorMsg(iSwApp, "SWCAMObject object not found");
Debug.WriteLine($"SWCAMObject loaded: {SWCAMObject}");

SWCAM = SWCAMObject.CAMWORKSADDINLib;    <---- Breaks here, not at all sure how to extract the addin interface.
if (SWCAM == null) ErrorMsg(iSwApp, "SWCAM object not found");
Debug.WriteLine($"SWCAM loaded: {SWCAM}");
```

Does anyone know how to extract the Solidworks CAM interface correctly?

Question has also been asked here:
https://forum.solidworks.com/thread/246718

--- Update ---
Following Sinues advice works!
I can't add the dll's he's referring to, I get the following error:
"... could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component."
However i've added the COM references:
SOLIDWORKS CAM 2021 Type Library
CAMWorksAddin 1.0 Type Library
And this seem to work

My final code which is running is:

```
CAMWORKSADDINLib.MWAddin addinObject = iSwApp.GetAddInObject(@"{CCAC6208-0E19-6455-2017-2021CEB541FA}");  
if (addinObject == null) ErrorMsg(iSwApp, "SWCAMObject object not found");  
Debug.WriteLine($"SWCAMObject loaded: {addinObject}");  

CAMWORKSLib.CWApp cwApp = addinObject.GetCWApp();  
if (cwApp == null) ErrorMsg(iSwApp, "SWCAM object not found");  
Debug.WriteLine($"SWCAM loaded: {cwApp}");  

Debug.WriteLine(cwApp.GetVersion());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to add a reference to the following DLL files to gain access to intellisense:

- C:\Program Files\SOLIDWORKS 2021\SOLIDWORKS CAM\camworksu.dll
- C:\Program Files\SOLIDWORKS 2021\SOLIDWORKS CAM\cwapiu.dll

Then you can get the addin object as you already did but as a specific object (MWAddin):

```
CAMWORKSADDINLib.MWAddin addinObject = swApp.GetAddInObject(@"{CCAC6208-0E19-6455-2017-2021CEB541FA}");
```

And to access the interface API (of cwapiu.dll):

```
CAMWORKSLib.CWApp cwApp = addinObject.GetCWApp();
```

From here you will work with the **cwApp** object and the object types of the **CAMWORKSLib** library

Comment: This Works!
I can't add the dll's you're referring to, I get the following:
"... could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component."

However i've added the COM references:
SOLIDWORKS CAM 2021 Type Library
CAMWorksAddin 1.0 Type Library
And this seem to work.

Comment: My final code which is running is:  
`code`
            CAMWORKSADDINLib.MWAddin addinObject = iSwApp.GetAddInObject(@"{CCAC6208-0E19-6455-2017-2021CEB541FA}");  
            if (addinObject == null) ErrorMsg(iSwApp, "SWCAMObject object not found");  
            Debug.WriteLine($"SWCAMObject loaded: {addinObject}");  
  
            CAMWORKSLib.CWApp cwApp = addinObject.GetCWApp();  
            if (cwApp == null) ErrorMsg(iSwApp, "SWCAM object not found");  
            Debug.WriteLine($"SWCAM loaded: {cwApp}");  
  
            Debug.WriteLine(cwApp.GetVersion());  
`code`